# Voting on a question after having clicked the upvotes/downvotes count will display an incorrect value

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

Choose a question you haven't voted on yet, click on the rating so it will show the amount of upvotes and downvotes. After that, vote on it. If the question has a rating of -15, it will show "16" instead of "-14".

**EDIT**:
Now with freehand circles and drop shadows, enjoy

[alt text http://uploads.segfaulting.com/1.PNG](http://uploads.segfaulting.com/1.PNG) [alt text http://uploads.segfaulting.com/2.PNG](http://uploads.segfaulting.com/2.PNG)

Now a bounty since this bug really bugs me. No pun intended!

Comment: This also happens for any starting value. Simply show the up/downvote count, vote and see the magic. Your question is at 3/1 right now. If I upvote you, it should be `4 - 1 = 3`, yet it shows 5 `(4 - (-1))`. The same thing would happen if I'd downvote you. It would still show 5 `(3 - (-2))`.

Comment: I see it as well.

Comment: @Daniel it's hard to miss it.

Comment: A better question... Why were you upvoting a question with 13 downvotes? Sympathy votes just add to the problem of separating the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: @gnostradamus: To demonstrate the behavior, after that I canceled the upvote as I suggested everyone else to do in my bug report. I thought it was obvious? I'm not sure what's up with meta and people not understanding examples.

Comment: @Koper: I see what happened. @pi removed that part of your question when they edited it. Not sure why.

Comment: @gnostradamus: oh, I see.. I didn't realize he edited it out, it's not THAT obvious now then, sorry

Comment: @gnostradamus sorry if I over-edited, maybe I got a bit carried away. I just thought there was no point to that remark, I thought it was implied. Feel free to add that missing part back, if you like.

Comment: Aha, a bounty. So you're hoping Jeff et all care about the bounty, *and* will fix this within 7 days? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: something like that! :)

Comment: Image links broken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed - thank you for finding this!

Comment: It might be helpful to explain a bit about what the problem was. That way if someone does a Google search because they are having a similar problem, they can figure out how to fix it themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Confirmed.

Before voting, the votes on this question stood at +1/-1 (normalized as 0). I upvoted it, and I got a big juicy 3, or when turned into two numbers, +2/-1. Removing the upvote left a 2.

Trying downvoting this time, +1/-1 downvote-> 1, or when turned into two numbers, +1/-2, and when reversed, the result was also wrong (I failed to write this one down).

I upvoted and downvoted a few times, reversing the vote each time, and got the "normalized" count up to a 4 before the vote window ran out.

Looks like some javascript has lots its marbles!

No screenshots with freehand circles; sorry to disappoint everyone.

Comment: I think it's related to the new design of the individual votes

Comment: I remember it being very difficult getting the hang of negative numbers too... mind you, I was 10 at the time :)

Comment: @Æther: I actually think this new feature is pretty cool. Yes, I think everybody who was smart enough to get 1000 rep understood it, but the new interface looks much cooler.

Comment: Agreed! I believe the colours were added first, and then the +/- a few hours later.. I *think* it's best now, but simply the colours would have been fine too.

Comment: The colours need to be tweaked to make them distinguishable by those with red/green colour blindness.

Comment: @ChrisF: wouldn't that be the point of the +/-?

Comment: @The Big Cheese you're right. How much more obvious can this thing be made? I think we're splitting hairs on the functionality.

Comment: @The Big Cheese - I'm not with it today at all. Must engage brain before typing.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, if you show the number of upvotes and downvotes and then you vote (doesn't matter if you upvote or downvote), it will simply add the 2 values and come up with a new, **wrong** value. It doesn't matter if the initial value vas negative, as Koper thought.

His question as I'm writing is at 4/1 votes. If I upvote, the split count will disappear and it will simply show me 6 (although it should be only 4). If I downvote, the same thing will happen, the vote count will incorrectly show me 6 (`4 + 2` instead of `4 - 2`). I think it simply adds the number of downvotes and upvotes together, instead of substracting the downvotes.

Comment: Like you commented yourself a few minutes before posting this answer: it's probably +4 minus -2, which indeed yields 6. So, it's *probably* subtracting, but using the negative number for the downvotes.