# Vote split feature temporarily miscalculates reputation after up-vote

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Voting on a question after having clicked the upvotes/downvotes count will display an incorrect value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/voting-on-a-question-after-having-clicked-the-upvotes-downvotes-count-will-displa)

Although not a show stopper, there's a minor bug in the way that the total reputation is recalculated after voting up a post immediately after viewing the vote split.

Locate a question or answer that has *both* upvotes and down downvotes and click on the reputation value to show the voting split (you need to do this anyway to find them). For example:

> [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes)

At the time I looked at this question it had a rep score of 89 comprised of +91/-2 votes

If I then clicked on the upvote button it recalculated the repution total as being 94 instead of 90. Refreshing the page in my browser then shows the correct new score as being 90, so it's really a UI bug rather than a server side data thing.

It looks like there's some wonky addition going there, i.e. the downvote value is being added to the upvote value as an absolute value instead of as-is.

Here's some screen-shots with the obligatory free hand circles/annotation:

**Browse to question:**

[Step1 http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/9613/97768180.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/9613/97768180.png)

**Show vote split:**

[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/8731/30308500.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/8731/30308500.png)

**Click upvote:**

[alt text http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/337/47399994.png](http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/337/47399994.png)

Comment: It's a caching thing.

Comment: Must look harder..

Comment: Nice try with the freehand circles though!

Comment: @Æther - Thanks...I know....I'm gutted...took me ages to do because of the limited time you have to play with votes :)