# Vote split does not include leading sign when count exceeds 99

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I don't care, and I can only imagine it's very much **[status-bydesign]** to preserve some real estate (though larger numbers use a smaller font anyhow). Still, *just* in case it matters, especially for downvotes:

When the number of up or down votes exceeds 99, then the leading plus or minus sign is not shown in the [vote split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes):

[image: +99 up / -3 down]     [image: 100 up / -1 down]     [image: 1147 up / 107 down]

The sign is also "missing" in the Ajax response. For the above images, the JSON [results](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/332010/vote-counts):

```
{"up":"+99","down":"-3"}
```

[versus](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/236751/vote-counts):

```
{"up":"100","down":"-1"}
```

[and](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/164556/vote-counts):

```
{"up":"1147","down":"107"}
```

If the JavaScript code ever relies on the minus sign (like [it once seemed to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/voting-on-a-question-after-having-clicked-the-upvotes-downvotes-count-will-displa)) then *in theory* this might be an issue.

Comment: Let's downvote this post 100 times and see what happens.

Comment: Questions page, sort by votes? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-do-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user-work-the-official-faq

Comment: @Kop, downvoting? No problem! But then: how to get at least 100 views...? :-) (Actually, before posting the above, I thought I might find some heavily downvoted post using a datadump, but neither http://stackql.net/ nor http://statoverflow.com/sandbox seem to be available. Any ideas, other than just importing myself? Sorting the questions by vote gets me something like -48, not even close to a cigar. Maybe a 10k can find some deleted post?)

Comment: Ah, found a post through [What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites)

Comment: stackql.net isn't forwarded anymore, but you can use http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/

Comment: Now that dyndns is no longer free, I'm at http://coehoorn.no-ip.org/stackql/ -- but really, just use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Jeff Atwood's answer does not jibe with the data...

1. The UI must already deal with [5-digit numbers, **WITH a plus sign**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/331508):
   [image: Largest vote count so far]
2. This means the UI could **easily handle a 5-digit downvote number**, WITH a minus sign.
   ***Mockup*** (with page viewed at 200%):
   [image: What the UI should be]
3. But, in fact, [there are **no posts with more than 400 downvotes**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/826570/posts-having-100-or-more-downvotes)<sup>See [meta for the worst](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/826570/posts-having-100-or-more-downvotes)</sup>. So, we are orders of magnitude away from what the UI must already handle.

Comment: There is now a [MetaSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/209901) with 2289 downvotes and a [MetaSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389908/1983854) with 1033 downvotes, as of writing.

Answer (score -2):

This is by design so the numbers fit more easily in the available space.

Comment: So why not make the JSON feed without the sign? That's one thing I absolutely hate about all JSON feeds on Stack Overflow... They depend too much on the VIEW, when in fact they should be DATA (model)... Especially the Flair JSON.

Comment: @andrew how so? +7 is a number just like -3.

Comment: +7 is a string... 7 is an integer. And if the `+` disappears when it is too long to display, then you are passing VIEW instead of DATA.

Comment: So if `"down":"-3"` is a downvote, couldn't `"down":"107"` be mistaken for an upvote?

Comment: @coredump The key already tells you it is a "down"-vote, there is no mistaking unless you take it out of context. And you could just use `value.up - Math.abs(value.down)` to compute the net vote. (And I think the JSON should return numbers instead of strings, and don't include any sign at all).

Comment: @kennytm I agree, but that's ugly. Bugs thrive with things like this.

Comment: +7 and 7 are two *representations* of the number known in the English language as "seven"

Comment: @Pac0: But -7 and 7 are not two _representations_ of the number known in the English language as "minus seven".