# More and more images go missing. Can the cooked HTML be rebuilt?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, imgur

Would it be doable to re-generate the cooked (cached) HTML of all posts that hold images and  were last edited between August 16 2010 and June 21 2011?

Many references to `i.imgur.com` were automatically changed into `i.stack.imgur.com` ([around June 20th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734)). But it seems that for many posts the cooked HTML was not updated after the Markdown source was changed.

Like:

```
![+99 up / -3 down][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvZxk.png
```

...still outputs [its cooked HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/vote-split-does-not-include-leading-sign-when-count-exceeds-99) without the `stack` part, as:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QoQV.png" alt="+99 up / -3 down">
```

But https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QoQV.png, without `stack`, [no longer works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqc2g.png)<sup>†</sup>.

The [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/45436/revisions) and the preview generate the HTML on the fly, and hence *do* show the images as then the URL *does* include `stack` (making this even [more confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110521/why-does-the-source-of-this-question-not-remain-the-same-when-viewing-and-editin)).

A simple dummy edit fixes it, but not many will know about that. I myself seem to have [a guardian angel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z9ud.png) who fixes all my images by doing a full re-upload. But I feel that shouldn't be needed.

As an aside: if the HTML would be cooked (cached) upon first request, then "all" this takes is clearing the cooked HTML for those posts? That would distribute the server load for regenerating the HTML over a much longer period. (But it seems that currently the conversion [is not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48596/when-does-the-question-answer-text-get-converted-from-markdown-to-html/48598#48598) on first page request.)

<sup><sup>†</sup> Even though those were originally uploaded using the toolbar button, to the [Stack Exchange Imgur pro account](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), which should not expire to start with?</sup>

Comment: It is, by the way, not Super User only. I've also made some [dummy](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1348248/revisions) [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1324720/revisions) on SO.

Comment: I've seen this on Meta.SO & SO as well, I can't recall the links though

Comment: True, @Sathya, like [this question on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/55162/revisions). But it's not a problem for every post. Like the Markdown for [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75105/is-imgur-losing-images) has not been edited since January, but *does* include the new `stack` in the image URLs. (The latter is a confusing example though, as the image is actually a 404 image itself...) I've seen it happen in both questions and answers.

Comment: 4 weeks later, now 2 of the 3 images of [a specific post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/vote-split-does-not-include-leading-sign-when-count-exceeds-99) no longer work. [October 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UgdSI.png), [October 30](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eqc2g.png), ...

Comment: @Team, I know [you know about it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/783548/revisions)! ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just in time for Christmas we went on a cooking spree and baked up fresh post bodies for any post that had a reference to the new i.stack.imgur.com in the revision history and had not yet been updated on the main post body.

Mmmm - delicious post bodies.

Comment: That's what *she* said.