# imgur links broken by stackoverflow

Tags: bug, imgur

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More and more images go missing. Can the cooked HTML be rebuilt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt)

I just noticed that the uploaded images in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782375/which-is-more-popular-currently-by-recent-install-base-svn-or-cvs/783548#783548) are broken. Images with this text are being shown instead:

```
The image you are
requesting does not exist
or is no longer available.

imgur.com
```

Curiously the images show up just fine when I clicked "edit".

Apparently the correct URLs in the markdown start with `https://i.stack.imgur.com`, but stackoverflow rewrites these into broken URLs that start with `http://i.imgur.com`.

Comment: No man, its [_imgur_ breaks urls starting with i.stack.imgur.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111619/old-i-stack-imgur-com-links-stop-working-after-a-while) after a few months

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly they didn't look broken to me; here's one - looks fine:

[image: old url]

However, just to make sure, I've edited it to force a re-render, and it now has the stack urls:

[image: new url]

Comment: The first image you post here is broken for me, see [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/119154/permalink/brokenimage.png). I guess we are not seeing the same thing.

Comment: @wcoenen I guess we're hitting different CDN nodes. Does the second one work?

Comment: yes, the second one works. I edited my previous comment to point to a screenshot.

Comment: Confirmed: The first one is broken, the second one works for me too. (From Germany)

Comment: Same thing as Pekka, from France.

Comment: Well, it works from the UK. So there!

Comment: I'm in the UK, same as @MarcGravell. I have no problems.

Comment: @tombull89 well, apart from the state of the economy, the education system, healthcare, public transport, banks, declining police numbers, bin collection, ...

Comment: Haha, the UK has been heaven-banned. They get to see what no body else can see any more.

Comment: Will you be at CodeKEN by the way Marc? (OT)

Comment: @Pekka I won't, I'm afraid. I am, however, recycling my devdays talk into Oredev (Thursday) and a few local user-groups (December, March)

Comment: @MarcGravell, yeah...that too...

Comment: Same like @Pekka and Israel here ;)

Comment: @Marc awwww, pity!

Comment: @Marc, now that [you made a dummy edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/783548/revisions) to that post, to enforce the `stack` to make it into the HTML: you're aware of [More and more images go missing. Can the cooked HTML be rebuilt?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt), right?