# i.stack.imgur.com images stop working after a while

Tags: support, images, imgur

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More and more images go missing. Can the cooked HTML be rebuilt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt)

I noticed this a long time ago, but it appears that old i.stack.imgur.com images stop working after a couple of months.

Most recent example is https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTKoa.png from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87656/root-tags-to-organize-larger-sites-with-multiple-categories).

But https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaMH7.png (deleting the `stack` portion) *does* work.

Somebody needs to get their poo together (lookin' at you imgur.com)

Comment: Hey uh, @Dori this is about Imgur to stop breaking links with i.stack.imgur.com in them.. the issue isn't about re-cooking HTML, its about imgur

Comment: It sounds to me like the same issue as yesterday's [imgur links broken by stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111358/imgur-links-broken-by-stackoverflow).

Comment: You might find [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying) useful too, even though Dori [apparently disagrees](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/111619/revisions)

Comment: @Michael - Some reasons: (1) that link (the older one) is a support request that's received an accepted answer. The more recent one, though, is a bug report with no `status-` tag (i.e., it's something in need of a fix). (2) bobobobo's question mentioned "images stop working after a couple of months", and the more recent link refers to "images go[ing] missing." The older link doesn't. (3) The more recent one links to the older in its second paragraph, so it's not as if anything is lost by only referencing the newer.

Comment: Voting to re-open as this seems to be the exact opposite of my request. [My post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt) describes how images *without* `stack` go missing (while the Markdown source actually refers to the version *with* `stack`, though the cooked HTML does not.) But in the above bug report, somehow the images *with* `stack` are faulty. That's an even bigger issue, @Dori!

Comment: @Arjan - I read both as saying that, for some problem images, using `i.stack.imgur` does not work, but `i.imgur` does (i.e., "...still renders without the `stack` part"). If that's not what you meant to report, then the other question should be rewritten first.

Comment: @Dori, in my post, *render* referred to the outputted HTML, not to whether or not the image was visible (hence the following lines with the HTML fragment). So, the HTML still refers to the old image URL *without* stack, which unfortunately go missing more and more. I edited it a bit to clarify some more, I hope. Still voting to re-open!

Comment: Ok I see what happened. To reiterate on 2011/06/20 SO team did a weird thing and renamed all imgur image urls in all posts to start with `i.stack.imgur.com`.  I think they did this to prevent imgur from deleting the images if they are not viewed for 6 months.  If you uploaded the image _not_ thru the stackoverflow interface, then your image will not have been replicated to `i.stack.imgur.com`, and so it will be a broken link now. The best thing to do is to edit the post, re-insert the image (using "from web") into the post, so it starts with `i.stack.imgur.com` now

Comment: Okay, then it's a duplicate of [Images manually uploaded to Imgur are not displaying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying) (like @Michael suggested) after all!

Comment: (By the way: SE officially did not do this to preserve images from being lost after 6 months, as images that were uploaded using the toolbar button were uploaded to SE's Pro account anyhow —before the `stack` part [was even introduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com/94286#94286)— from which no images should disappear either. Meanwhile we know better though: images in the Pro account *do* disappear. Or maybe the Pro account without the `stack` part is simply no longer officially a Pro account?)

Comment: No man, the images in the Pro account do not disappear.  The broken link images all come from people who uploaded images __not using the in-site SO interface__, which is what I had been doing.  Renaming image URLs to start with `stack` could have been __a lot__ more graceful if they actually CHECKED if the image 404'd before the rename occurred, and if it 404'd then that image should have been replicated into the SO pro account.  Oh well.

Comment: I know, but you wrote *"I think they did this to prevent imgur from deleting the images if they are not viewed for 6 months"*, which (officially) is not true.