# No plus sign when viewing vote counts that are 3 digits or more

Tags: feature-request, design, vote-count

When viewing vote counts, the number of upvotes is right after the green plus sign as seen here:

[image]

There were 91 upvotes to this post so when viewing vote counts, it shows the `+` then the number of upvotes, which is 91. This applies to every posts' vote counts no matter what score... unless it has three digit numbers. So as seen here, any vote count with more than 99 upvotes will have no plus sign:

[image]

People might think it is because the vote counts can only hold 3 chars for each section under the `---`, but it can also hold 4 digit numbers:

[image]

This is pretty weird really. So can we have the plus sign back for the vote count numbers with at least three digits?

Comment: Have fun with your new VTC privilege ;)

Comment: I'd rather remove the plus and minus signs for all numbers. They're pretty pointless.

Comment: Well, [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/vote-split-does-not-include-leading-sign-when-count-exceeds-99) was closed as [tag:status-bydesign] so most likely this feature request is going to be [tag:status-declined]

Comment: I agree with animusion. It's so obvious. Green color denotes the Upvotes and Red for Downvotes. As long the UI part is kept consistent across all the SE verticals. I like the arrangement divided by gray color line. Upvotes sits at the Upper level and Downvotes sits at the Down level.