# 0 upvotes, 1 downvote, total 0?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, vote-count

This answer

[structured vs. unstructured data in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695582/structured-vs-unstructured-data-in-db/2703917#2703917)

has a score of 0, but when I click on the score I see zero upvotes and one downvote, which add up to -1.

Refreshing the page does not help, nor does clearing the cache.

This looks similar to an older (fixed) bug: [Voting on a question after having clicked the upvotes/downvotes count will display an incorrect value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/voting-on-a-question-after-having-clicked-the-upvotes-downvotes-count-will-displa), but is not quite the same - I have not voted on this answer (I could not possibly have, because I am its owner) and I don't think it can be a cache or AJAX issue either; The downvote appears to be legitimate (it reduced my reputation.)

---

**Update** - when I checked again an hour later, the correct total of -1 was shown (with no new votes) so whatever is causing this effect it is only temporary.

Comment: Addition and subtraction are hard for these poor computers, you know...

Comment: Strange, it's showing up with a -1 total for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [You can deduce how many flags a post has](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has)

Comment: @Jon Seigel, the linked question was asked 4 days after mine.

Comment: @Per: Yes, I know. That question gained more traction (sorry) and there are many duplicates already linking to it. For purposes of people finding the same information, it's better to close this question as a duplicate of the other regardless of the time the question is asked.

Comment: I observe this today at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049515/how-to-work-with-html-code-readed-on-java/7049831#7049831 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that -1 point getting from **flags** take some times to reflect to total score, normal downvotes isn't.

**Note**: your post got a spam flag.

Comment: Wouldn't 5 (or is it 6) spam flags cost me 100 rep (and auto delete the post?) It only cost me 2 rep.  A single flag doesn't affect rep does it?

Comment: @Per, each flags does effect rep by -2, you could try on my answer, and check before and after reps.