# You can deduce how many flags a post has

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, user-interface, flags

Now that the -1 for flags is denormalized, you can find out how many flags a post has if you have more than 1000 reputation.

Real life example:

A question looks like this
[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/pre.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/pre.png)
And if you click the -3, you see
[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/post.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/post.png)
Instead of +1/-4.
It's easy to deduce the post has 2 flags, even if you don't have access to 10k tools:
[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/flags.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/flags.png)

I'm pretty sure this isn't intended.

Comment: No-repro: [Jeff's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/a-better-notification-of-significant-modifications-on-the-trilogy/48095#48095) has +4 -12 = -8, but it has 3 flags. Same [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki/47998#47998). Although it works on [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48024/what-is-up-with-everyone-always-saying-plz-help/48065#48065)... strange

Comment: I think it is related to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47877/vote-total-doesnt-decrease-with-1-anymore-after-flagging-as-spam). You'll only see this discrepancy during the period when the vote total isn't updated.

Comment: 4 actually @bal, I don't want to link to my example, but it's the third currently in the flag list, check it out

Comment: Oh, I see @cco, the problem still remains, you can see if a post has flags (at least for a period of time) and that info is not supposed to be public (for < 10k)

Comment: Well, you can also read comments on deleted questions *even when you're logged out*. Oh well...

Comment: You know, at this point I'm willing to bet that Jeff's gotten more flags than RichB ever got on here.

Comment: only 1 more to the funniest -100 in the history of SO @eth

Comment: Just guessing, but as these downvotes (cast by the community user) will [age away if the post does not reach the offensive threshold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40568/double-downvote-by-flagging-as-spam-and-downvoting/44376#44376), I assume it is by design to not add those to the total value. (Which, of course, does not justify why they are visible in the vote split details, which is the subject of this very question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this in dev it will be deployed later tonight.

Comment: Is the fix that flags cause the post's score to be recalculated immediately?

Comment: @Michael nope, it just keeps the UI in a consistent state.

Comment: Am I right to assume that the flag-downvotes will not be added to the total? In other words: am I right to assume that in the above example the total score will still be -3, not -5? (I might be wrong, given [Double downvote by flagging as spam AND downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40568/double-downvote-by-flagging-as-spam-and-downvoting))

Answer (score 2):

I'm reproducing; so far, I haven't been able to reproduce on questions, but on answers. If you go to the tool->flags section and just click on any random flagged answer, you'll get the discrepancies.

**Update:** It appears to only happen to spam flagged answers. Offensive flagged answers don't appear to exhibit the behavior.