# Should there really be a badge for flagging?

Tags: discussion, badges, flags

I don't think there should be a badge for flagging a post because it can encourage new users to flag **just to get the badge**.

Comment: There is a *badge* for flagging? Since when?

Comment: @Pekka *There is!* I didn't know until I flagged this post, but there definitely is...

Comment: @Tyler Really? Didn't know that. What's it named? (Off to flag some other post so this doesn't get deleted :)

Comment: @Tyler Chacha: You flagged my post? :'(

Comment: @Pekka Citizen Patrol.

Comment: @Grace yeah, I see now, cheers. @Linuxmint this is Meta, never mind, people like to play around here :)

Comment: @Linuxmint never mind that either. Downvotes have a different role on Meta than on SO: They are used as an expression of disagreement. Anybody disagreeing with your request would downvote

Comment: Also, complaining about being "voted down" is asking for more downvotes...

Comment: No more complaints! :P

Comment: I just noticed a "bug". I have gotten 2 upvotes on this post, and  2 downvotes. But the post shows up as "-1". Shouldn't it show up as "0"?

Comment: It's because you have a flag in addition to two downvotes. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has).

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you asked not to be flagged... see? you have to use reverse psychology here, except in the cases where you don't.

Comment: @Juan Manuel: So if I used reverse psychology then everyone would know that I did and It wouldn't effect them, So I would have to use reverse reverse psychology and that would be normal. But since I am saying this then you would know that I wouldn't use reverse psychology so I should use reverse psychololgy and so on...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One potential problem with flagging badges is that they are awarded immediately. This can make flagging non anonymous in case you cast your first flag on a post and that flag causes a post to disappear.

This happened to me on Area51, a site with relatively low activity...

Answer (score 6):

But it could also encourage people to flag when necessary.

I do believe that people flagging just to get the badge get what they deserve (since a moderator will look at the post and see nothing wrong).

Comment: This is phrased in a way that may be misleading, so I will clarify -- Citizen Patrol is only awarded for flagging as spam or offensive. Flagging for moderator attention does not award the badge.

Comment: A successful flag, or any flag?  I think that it should only reward the flaggers that are being useful to moderators.

Answer (score 1):

Any tool or rule can be misused. I don't think it make this badge useless.