# Total up/down votes incorrect after retracting vote on answer with no other votes

Tags: bug

See this video:

http://screencast.com/t/JsMiMbOyyqYU

**[Edit] This is not due to posts being flagged** - I can reproduce it on any answer which has 0 votes.

**[Edit 2]** This appears to be fixed.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47784 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51616 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53997 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68190

Comment: Meh, looks fine to me.  Math is hard...just let it be. `:P`

Comment: That video made me a dizzy \*_\*