# Wrong score for answer? (1-1=1)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749015/i-need-to-write-a-program-that-reads-angles-in-radians-from-an-input-disk-and-con/2749231#2749231) shows a score of **1** right now:

[alt text http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/1979/so1.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/1979/so1.png)

When I click the score to *show total up and down vote counts*, it shows (**+1** / **-1**), so I would expect total score to be **0**:

[alt text http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/8034/so0.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/8034/so0.png)

I refreshed several times and I can reproduce it with 3 different browsers.

I found this bug ([Voting on a question after having clicked the upvotes/downvotes count will display an incorrect value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/voting-on-a-question-after-having-clicked-the-upvotes-downvotes-count-will-displa)), but **I did not vote** for this answer.

---

Can you reproduce this? Anyone seen that before?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has

Answer (score 5):

This can happen as the score is denormalized.

It gets fixed (now) two ways:

1. Someone votes on it, which checks the db again.
2. The daily scripts fix all scores which don't match the db.

Comment: What sort of scenario could create this, though?

Comment: @Phoshi: I would imagine maybe if the account that voted was deleted

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has

Comment: @Downvoter: Thanks, that would actually explain it! This behavior is, well, surprising...