# Question has a score of -2, yet when I click on the score, the details show 0 upvotes and -3 downvotes

Tags: bug, questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Wrong score for answer? (1-1=1)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48501/wrong-score-for-answer-1-11)
>   [Vote total doesn’t decrease with -1 anymore after flagging as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47877/vote-total-doesnt-decrease-with-1-anymore-after-flagging-as-spam)

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848515/seo-training-in-karachi-facebook-fan-pages) has a score of -2, yet when I click on the score, the details show 0 upvotes and 3 downvotes. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it has been flagged as spam or offensive which adds a temporary -1 from the community user.

(if the threshold is not reached, the downvote from community is aged away and disappears)