# Number of downvotes and upvotes count differs from summarized count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [You can deduce how many flags a post has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has)

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956094/this-is-a-test-title-and-this-is-cool) which was closed just now showed -12 votes. But when the count was clicked, it showed 0 upvotes and -13 downvotes. Why is that so? Is it because it was closed and people are trying to downvote and is not reflected.

Comment: This is most likely related to the things discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47877/

Comment: jeff's answer here explaining that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50165/question-has-a-score-of-2-yet-when-i-click-on-the-score-the-details-show-0-upv

Answer (score 0):

Someone has clicked downvote between the the page loaded and when you clicked the count.

Refresh the page to see.

Comment: I've refreshed the page many times to see this surprize. The weird thing was that the downvote count still increased, the summarized count being the same.