# Total upvote and downvote counts are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [You can deduce how many flags a post has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has)

There are a few questions on here that appear to be duplicates but either claim to be completed or related to answers being voted upon while the page is being viewed:

> - [Voting on a question after having clicked the upvotes/downvotes count will display an incorrect value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/voting-on-a-question-after-having-clicked-the-upvotes-downvotes-count-will-displa)
> - [Number of downvotes and upvotes count differs from summarized count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52116/number-of-downvotes-and-upvotes-count-differs-from-summarized-count)

Here is the [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257229/what-are-these-called/3257253#3257253) I was about to delete when I was curious the amount of up vs. downvotes it had received:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJrQ2.png]

And after expanding the vote totals:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAlRr.png]

Now I'm not a doctor, but `5 - 13 != -4`!

Comment: It's a flagging thing - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47877/vote-total-doesnt-decrease-with-1-anymore-after-flagging-as-spam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer has 5 upvotes, 9 downvotes, and 4 people flagged it offensive, which show up as downvotes in the total vote breakdown (see the fourth bullet [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work/22175#22175)). The vote summary total is cached and (apparently) flags don't force an update; the breakdown is not cached and always shows the most recent data

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea flagging as offensive counts as a downvote. I also have no idea how that post is offensive.

Comment: @John They might be spam votes. A lot of people use "spam" as a substitute for "noise" since there's no option to flag as noise. And it's really not addressing the actual question. I wouldn't flag it myself.

Comment: @Grace They are offensive, it shows up in the list of flags today. Spam does get abused regularly for that though

Comment: Ah, I forgot that non-diamonds can actually see the flags assigned, and just assumed that when you said "4 people flagged it offensive" you were less saying that they specifically flagged it as offensive as you were saying that it was flagged. My bad.

Comment: is there any way to check the total upvote per users?

Answer (score 0):

did you try refreshing the page? 
The information is "aggressively cached" which means that in the time between when you loaded the page and when you clicked on the number (which causes a separate call) the information may have changed.